# Method that looks at an int array and ignores multiples of a number

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int

i'm making a method that ignores multiples. The input is..
`int[] Eliminate = new int[]{1, 54, 20, 17, 60};`

this is the code..

```
public static int[] EliminateMultiples(int[] List, int Num) {
int[] New = new int[List.length];
    int NewListIndex = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<List.length; i++) { 
        if ((List[i] % Num !=0 )) {
            New[NewListIndex] = List[i];
        }
        NewListIndex++;
        System.out.println(New[i]);
    }
    return New;
}
```

The problem i'm getting is that the output has zeros in it. I think it's because I made the length of the new list to the old list even though the new list would maybe not have as many numbers.

Comment: Can you use an `ArrayList<Integer>` or are you obliged to use `int[]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with Java 8 Streams:

```
public static int[] eliminateMultiples(int[] list, int num) {
    return Arrays.stream(list).filter(i -> i % num != 0).toArray();
}
```

If you also want to print each element, you can `peek` into the stream and print them:

```
public static int[] eliminateMultiples(int[] list, int num) {
    return Arrays.stream(list).filter(i -> i % num != 0).peek(System.out::println).toArray();
}
```

If you really need to use arrays, you need at least 2 loops:

1. Counting the number of elements:

   ```
   int count = 0;
   for (int element : list) {
       if (element % num != 0)
           count++;
   }
   ```
2. Creating the array with the number of elements (from 1.) and filling it.

   ```
   int[] result = new int[count];
   int i = 0;
   for (int element : list) {
       if (element % num != 0) {
           result[i++] = element;
       }
   }
   return result;
   ```

As you can see, this is a lot more to write.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that will make you an array that is right size. It is different from because NewListIndex is putted into if, and in the end array is "trimed" to be right length.

```
public static int[] EliminateMultiples(int[] List, int Num) {
    int[] New = new int[List.length];
    int NewListIndex = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<List.length; i++) { 
        if ((List[i] % Num !=0 )) {
            New[NewListIndex] = List[i];
             NewListIndex++;
        }

    }
    int [] ret=Arrays.copyOfRange(New, 0, NewListIndex);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Also, there is probably no need for this to bi static method, but it will not make you any problems, saying it just because you should learn what static means.